# Why gcov is not covering logical && operator?

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcov, gcovr, ceedling

My piece of code which I am doing unit testing on is something like this:

```
     if(((State !=TCPIP_IPADDR_STATE_ASSIGNED)&& (State !=TCPIP_IPADDR_STATE_ONHOLD) && (State !=TCPIP_IPADDR_STATE_UNASSIGNED)) ||(SoConId==DOIP_INVALID_16))
       {
        }
```

And my unit test case includes following :

```
`DoIP_LocalIpAddrAssignmentChg(12,0xFF);`
```

Where DoIP_LocalIpAddrAssignmentChg is the function name in which if is located and 0xFF is for invalid state which is obviously not equal to all 3 : **TCPIP_IPADDR_STATE_ASSIGNED**, **TCPIP_IPADDR_STATE_ONHOLD**, **TCPIP_IPADDR_STATE_UNASSIGNED**. 
The value of **SoConId** is **12**. The value of **DOIP_INVALID_16** = **0xFF**.

So when I check my unit test report, its gives this result:
[image: code coverage for if condition]
My question is why it's not covering condition for **TCPIP_IPADDR_STATE_UNASSIGNED** as value for state I am passing is **0xFF** which is invalid value.

Comment: The code you posted is *not* the code you tested. -- And you don't need the backslash in C source, only on preprocessor lines that have to be one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a "victim" of lazy evaluation.

Chapter 6.5.14 "Logical OR opeartor":

> If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

All three parts of the multiple-AND are `true`, and so unequal to 0.

Both logical `&&` are covered, but you can't see it because of the `||` in the same line not being fully executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to know is there any way to make evaluate it forcefully ? Any compilation flags?

Comment: If you dare to read through the hundreds of GCC options, you might find one. -- Anyway, I don't know for sure, but you might like to try to compile without optimization, for GCC by the option `-O0`. This is always a good idea while testing, because optimized code may fold instruction sequences together, leading to "funny" observations. -- However, as the standard *defines* lazy evaluation, even unoptimized code might take the short-cut.